Accessing index for animation on curves
I have a setup for an animation on a curve, but having some trouble accessing a specific index in order to turn only one of the squares blue, while the rest remain red.
I'm probably using this additional Capture Attribute incorrectly, so any hints on how to make this work is appreciated! The error I'm getting on the Set Material node is: "Curves only support a single field"



Geometry Nodes: What Does Capture Attribute Add to Geometry?

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
Analysis
The information message displayed by the Set Material node reads:

Curves only support a single material; selection input cannot be a field.

Consequently, to control the material per instance, different materials can be assign to different meshes input as instances in the Instances on Points node. Or the switch according the instances must be managed by the shading nodes associated to the single material assigned to the curve.
Approach 1: Material is controlled through the spawned object

Using the Pick Instance option, the blue grid is selected as the Instance with Index equal to 1 (because its rank is 2 in the collection generated by the Geometry to Instance node).
Approach 2: Color is stored as an attribute

A Color per instance is assigned with a Store Named Attribute node set in Instance domain. This Color is recovered in the shading graph using an Attribute node whose Type is set to Instancer, and it is input directly in the shader.
Approach 3: Instance index is stored as an attribute

The instance Index is saved by a Store Named Attribute node set in Instance domain. This value is recovered in the shading graph using an Attribute node whose Type is set to Instancer, through the Fac socket. It is then processed to compute the color that is input in the shader.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.1+)
